# Deserialize string (AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parameter)

Tags: c#, deserialization, httpresponse

I'm currently writing an error handling for some http requests.
For example, if the token is expired, I receive the following string in *response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate*:

```
"error=\"invalid_token\", error_description=\"The token is expired\""
```

The *string* is the *Paremeter* property of a *AuthenticationHeaderValue* object.
I tried *deserializing* the string with *JObject.Parse()* and *JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()* but it doesn't work. I guess it's because the JSON is *invalid* since the property names are *unquoted* and it uses *"="* instead of *":"*.

Is there simple way to parse that string?

Comment: You should check the authentication header for the `httprequest`, it might have an expired token.

Comment: @Carbine 
It's about deserializing the string from the response into an object. Not about the expired token.

Comment: Oops my bad, didnt read clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the exact same problem today. My solution will be to check if the parameter string is enclosed by braces and if not put them around and **then** deserialize it.
So it would be something like this:

```
var header = response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.FirstOrDefault();

if (header == null)
    return false;

if (header.Scheme != JwtBearerScheme)
    throw new Exception($"Fatal Error: Authentication scheme is { header.Scheme } instead of { JwtBearerScheme }.");

string parameter = header.Parameter;

if (!parameter.StartsWith("{") || !parameter.EndsWith("}"))
    parameter = "{ " + parameter + " }";

var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyErrorObject>(parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace "=" with ":" as well, so it would be:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyErrorObject>( "{ " + parameter.Replace("=", ":") + " }")
```